# Problem with paging in an SPGridView

Tags: paging, spgridview

We are using SPGridView and binding it to the database. Paging is also enabled.

The grid is showing 10 records as the pagesize is 10, but when we click on the next page it
says

*"There are no items to show in this view"*

The PageIndexChanging event code is:

```
void Grid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

  Grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  Grid.DataBind();

}
```

The Second problem is that when I select a row in SPGrid the date columns are empty.

Does anyone know how to do paging with SPGridView?

Answer (score 1):

Powlo has posted a couple of [great blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/powlo/archive/2007/03/23/Adding-paging-to-SPGridView-when-using-custom-data-sources.aspx) about using SPGridView including paging.

Comment: i Follow the same blog.

Comment: Answers that are solely links to other answers are not appropriate on SharePoint.SE. Please post some content from the link into your answer so that it answers the question on its own.